# How to test express middleware that depends on other vendor middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I wanna test a middleware function that inside calls a vendor middleware function. The middleware is:

```js
const expressJwt  = require('express-jwt');
const validateJwt = expressJwt({ secret: 'whatever' });

exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
    req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${req.query.access_token}`;
  }

  validateJwt(req, res, next);
};
```

I've tried to create a `sinon.spy()` object and pass it as `next` parameter, but is not called apparently.

Another approach I've tried is to check if exists `req.user`, since the purpose of the [`express-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) middleware is to validate and attach `user` to the `req` object. No luck with this neither.

I've seen the existence of [`chai-connect`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/chai-connect-middleware), but not sure how to use it.

Any ideas? Highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it with [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) and [`chai-connect`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/chai-connect-middleware):

In your mocha config:

```
chai.use(require('chai-connect-middleware'));
global.connect = chai.connect;
```

In your test:

```
describe('isAuthenticated', () => {
// Wrap call to chai.connect into a function to use params and return a Promise
const mockedMiddleware = (changeSecret) => {
  let oldToken;
  if (changeSecret) {
    oldToken = acessToken;
    acessToken = 'blabalblalba';
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connect.use(middleware.isAuthenticated)
      .req(req => {
        req.query = { access_token: acessToken };
      })
      .next((res) => {
        acessToken = oldToken;
        if (res && res.status === 401) {
          reject(res.message);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      })
      .dispatch();
  });
};

it('should validate correctly', () =>
  mockedMiddleware().should.be.fulfilled
);

it('should not validate', () =>
  mockedMiddleware(true).should.be.rejected
);
});
```